# Need way to share file pointer between source files in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, header, argv

I made a this file pointer in my code that should contain my log.txt file's address:

`FILE *log`

This address depends on the `argv[1]` from my main.c function, it could be something like this:

```
char address[200];
strcpy(address, argv[1]);
FILE *log;
log = fopen(address, "w");
```

I need the address pointed by `*log` to be visible in all my .c source files, because they will have some lines like this:

```
fprintf(log, "Comment to be printed on log.txt");
```

I know it's a bad way to make a log file, but my program is big enough so that changing all the log printing lines will take a considerable amount of time.

The file's address has to be defined using argv[1]. How do I define it before my functions can use it (And how do I make them identify it)?

Comment: Sorry but I don't buy the changing all source files take too much time. Learn about your IDE or use other tools to do this. Visual Studio handles that pretty easily and on Linux you can use sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `log` as a global variable, and declare it as external symbol by `extern FILE *log;` in other places that you use it.

Comment: So, I'll declare it as a global variable in main.c, and then, I'll just write `extern FILE *log` on the other source codes?

Comment: @user3203734 Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @user3203734 yes, keep in mind that this approach will make harder the programming task in a threaded environment. Instead you could declare `static` variables and program a logic to accessing them from the outside with `setters` and `getters`